# How to create another object from an existing object?

Tags: javascript

I want to create `expectedObj` from `currentObj` to be sent as response to the API. How can I do it?

The "value" and "label" will always have same values.

These are fixed set of keys. ignore_whitespace is not needed in expectedObj. No other keys are required to be removed.

```
    let currentObj =  {
          "partnerId": "1",
          "platform": {
              "label": "ADP",
              "value": "ADP"
          },
          "subPlatform": {
              "value": "Health",
              "label": "Health"
          },
          "activeIndicator": {
              "value": "Inactive",
              "label": "Inactive"
          },
          "partnerNotes": "",
          "ignore_whitespace": false
    }
```

```
   let expectedObj={
        "partnerId": "1",
        "platform": "ADP",
        "subPlatform": Health,
        "activeIndicator": "Inactive",
        "partnerNotes": ""
   }
```

What I have tried is this

```
for let (item in currentObj) {
 something
}
```

Comment: It’s not clear how the transformation relates. How does platform turn into “Home”? Or any of the other properties… Why not just explicitly create the second object if there’s no relationship between the two? Also, what have you *tried* so far?

Comment: Okay, with the edits it is getting closer. Will “value” and “label” always share the same value in the original?

Comment: Yes, the "value" and "label" will always have same values

Comment: Is this all of the keys you will have? Or does the solution need to work for a different set of keys as well? Does ignores white space need to get removed or can it stay in the expected result? Are there other keys that will need to be removed if they are false?

Comment: Yes these are the fixed set of keys. Ignore whitespace is not needed in our expectedObj. No other keys are required to be removed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will do the transforms you need (as discussed in the comments, no more keys are expected, values are always the same as labels, etc):

```js
let currentObj =  {
          "partnerId": "1",
          "platform": {
              "label": "ADP",
              "value": "ADP"
          },
          "subPlatform": {
              "value": "Health",
              "label": "Health"
          },
          "activeIndicator": {
              "value": "Inactive",
              "label": "Inactive"
          },
          "partnerNotes": "",
          "ignore_whitespace": false
    }
    
let expected = {
    ...currentObj,
    platform: currentObj.platform.value,
    subPlatform: currentObj.subPlatform.value,
    activeIndicator: currentObj.activeIndicator.value,
}

delete expected.ignore_whitespace;

console.log(expected);
```

Answer (score 2):

Something like this should do what you're looking for:

```
const expectedObj = Object.entries(currentObj).reduce((a, [k, v]) => {
  if (v?.value !== undefined) a[k] = v.value;
  else a[k] = v;
  return a;
}, {});
```

Expand this code snippet for a working example:

```js
const currentObj = {
  partnerId: '1',
  platform: {
    label: 'ADP',
    value: 'ADP',
  },
  subPlatform: {
    value: 'Health',
    label: 'Health',
  },
  activeIndicator: {
    value: 'Inactive',
    label: 'Inactive',
  },
  partnerNotes: '',
  ignore_whitespace: false,
};

const expectedObj = Object.entries(currentObj).reduce((a, [k, v]) => {
  if (v?.value !== undefined) a[k] = v.value;
  else a[k] = v;
  return a;
}, {});

console.log(expectedObj);
```